# Surgeons won't go on break

Tags: two-point-hospital

I'm playing Two Point Hospital (PC, via Steam, all DLCs). In the "Chasm 24" level, I have a strange problem where my surgeons and the nurses working in the surgery won't go on break.

Basically, what happens is that the surgeon and the nurse get assigned to the surgery and operate on a few patients. Eventually they get tired, which should trigger them to change status (to "On Break") and cause them to exit the room and go to the staff room/toilets/vending machines or wherever else they need to go to deal with their needs.

What's actually happening is that the status switches to "On Break" and the surgeon and nurse continue working. Eventually their happiness and energy get fully depleted and they threaten to quit, so I have to give them a raise and manually pick them up and drop them in the staff room.

At first I thought it was a pathing issue since I like to make my rooms the minimum dimensions and the surgery is rather cramped at that size. (Maybe they couldn't get to/from the changing area, was my theory.) But after resizing the surgery to 4x4 up from 4x3, the same issue persists.

Here's a screenshot of a surgery where this is happening. The surgeon is to the top-left; you can see she is totally exhausted. Not only that, but the game thinks she took her break and is actually still on it! (hence the 'on call' state.)

[image: Screenshot of surgery]

I've tried increasing the surgery size (the one in the screenshot is 4x4). I've tried deleting the existing surgeries and building new ones. I've tried hiring new surgeons. This is happening consistently with all of my surgeries (I have 2) and is only happening on the Chasm 24 level.

How can I get my surgeons to take their breaks properly without requiring manual intervention?